# С чем согласуется множественная форма глагола "есть" — "суть"?

Tags: грамматика, выбор-слов, глаголы, синонимы

У глагола "есть" есть множественная форма третьего лица — "суть". Если что-то (во множественном числе) является чем-то (во множественном числе), то использование этой формы логично. Например, "собаки суть животные".

Но какую форму корректно использовать во фразах, когда подлежащее в единственном числе, а сказуемое — во множественном, и наоборот?

Например, во фразах "жизнь есть/суть взлёты и падения" или "эти взлёты и падения есть/суть жизнь". Каким правилом это регулируется? (Можно оставить за скобками архаичность и необязательность этой формы.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот что об этом слове говорится в толковом словаре Кузнецова:
[СУТЬ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C). *Книжн.*
**1.** *(3 л. мн. наст. от глагола **быть**; также в значении **3 л. ед.**). (в предл. с главными членами сущ.).* Употребляетя в качестве связки. *Воинская учёба и дисциплина суть основа боеспособности армии. Пластика, живописность поз суть средства вспомогательные в драме.*
**2.** Употребляется перед перечислением в значении: *следующие. Занятие крестьянина суть пахота, молотьба хлеба, сенокос. Понятия, принимаемые почти всеми историками, суть свобода, равенство, прогресс, цивилизация, культура.*
[Обратите внимание: от глагола **быть**!]

В толковом словаре Ожегова:
**суть**, 3 л. мн. ч. наст. вр. от глаг. быть (стар.), теперь книжн. Обычно употребляется как связка в составе именного сказуемого при подлежащем со значением множественности: есть, является, представляет собой. *Теория и практика суть альфа и омега познания.*

В толковом словаре Дмитриева:
[**суть**](http://endic.ru/dmytriev/Sut-4596.html)
**[это есть]** *глаг., нсв., употр. нечасто*
**1.** В предложении слово **суть** употребляется в качестве связки между понятием и пояснением, толкованием.
*Земля, на которой мы живём, мы сами и весь материальный мир суть результат эволюционных изменений.*
[Земля, мы сами и весь мир суть **результат** (мн. ч. —> ед. ч.).]

Но когда роман был почти закончен, то само собой вдруг всплыло помимо писательской воли, запросилось на белые листы, что **трое его персонажей суть один человек**, который для того и был отведён в северную лесную пустыню, чтобы там в тишине и уединении сделать выбор... [Алексей Варламов. Купавна // «Новый Мир», 2000]

*Небесные **движения** суть не что иное, как ни на миг не прекращающаяся многоголосая **музыка**, воспринимаемая не слухом, а разумом* (Сборник статей. Библия и наука).

*Жизнь суть взлёты и падения; взлёты и падения суть жизнь* — думаю, оба варианта возможны (все зависит от контекста).

Answer (score 1):

Вообще не следует использовать слово ‟суть” в значении связки, так как в таком значении оно уже лет 100 не употребляется. Нельзя оставить за скобками его архаичность. Каким правилом оно может регулироваться, если оно мертво? Архаизмы не следует использовать, так как  они будут вызывать реакции от недоумения до непонимания.